# Importing data from Excel to SQL Server 2014 does not display correctly in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

[image]

How to display the data like the blue underline data in SQL Server? When I execute a select statement the data displays like the Red underline data.

Comment: When you say 'display in SQL Server' do you mean SSMS? It might just be that the client you are using can't show it. To find out whats is really stored type `SELECT UNICODE(SUBSTRING(YourField,6,1) As Val, YourField FROM YourTable`. This shows the unicode value at position 6. Unicode value for `[` is 91. What number do you see?

Comment: You might also need to export your Excel as unicode CSV (a text file) and import that instead. Excel is very good at messing up data

Answer (score 0):

You should store this data in "NVARCHAR" datatype. Have you declared the column as NVARCHAR? VARCHAR cannot read all fonts of local language.

Comment: Yes I did stored the data as  NVARCHAR(255)